# iterate over specific column up to a certain value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, iteration

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"type":['a','b','c', 'd','e'], "cost basis":[50, 40, 30, 20, 10], "value":[5, 25, 40, 10, 20]})
```

I am looking to iterate over the "value" column up to a certain value or sum in descending order.  Let's say 50, whereas if the next number exceeds that value then the iteration would stop there.

Comment: What is your expected output from the given dataframe?

Comment: For this example, let's just say 50.  So iterating the value column in descending order up to 50, then each of those rows in the dataframe up to that value would be added to a new dataframe.  This is for an accounting project I am working on so I am filtering down the dataset to sell specific tax lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that what you want but If I Understand correctly:

Try via `cumsum()`:

```
out=A.loc[A['value'].cumsum().le(50)]
```

OR

If want in descending order then use `sort_values()`+`cumsum()`:

```
out=A.loc[A.sort_values('value',ascending=False,ignore_index=True)['value'].cumsum().le(50)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using two functions: `cumsum` and `argmax`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame({"type":['a','b','c', 'd','e'], "cost basis":[50, 40, 30, 20, 10], "value":[5, 25, 40, 10, 20]})

# Cummulated sum of array A
acumsum = np.cumsum(A.value.values)

# Determine the first index where the value is greater than 50:
idx = np.argmax(acumsum > 50)

print(idx)
```